# How to write a link like <a href="#id"> which link to the same page in PHP?

Tags: php

like in HTML, I could write `<a href="#id">` which could link to the place where I make a `<a id="id">` . but it seems that it does not work in PHP. How to do that?

the original code is from bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

```
<div class='tabbable'>
<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li class='active'><a href='#tab1' data-toggle='tab'>Drinks</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2' data-toggle='tab'>Bread</a></li>
</ul>

<div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane active' id='tab1'><p>some</p>
    </div>

    <div class='tab-pane' id='tab2'><p>many</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but just when I turned to PHP, the tab link does not work

Comment: It's the same link if it originates in PHP or HTML. What doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Make sure your markup is well formed, and you haven't duplicated ids, for example. Post some code for use to examine...

Comment: actually i am using the codes from bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs. Because I want to connect to database so i use php. but the tab part just does not work...

Comment: That doesn't matter. If the HTML you output is well formed, the browser has no way of knowing or caring if it came from PHP or elsewhere.  So if it's not working, there may be something else in the way.

Comment: Look at the page source after the PHP renders to the browser. Does it look the same (including the bootstrap.js & css) as the original HTML version?

Comment: yes it does look the same. PHP one http://x69chen.com/msci_checkoutsystem.php, HTML one http://x69chen.com/employee-index/. just the tab link does not work

Comment: Extremely late, Just for curiousity, have you tried closing your parent div class 'tabbable'? It might not respond since the wrapper isn't closed.

Answer (score 14):

Edit:

Are you trying to do sth like this?
See: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

---

See the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/U6aKT/

```
<a href="#id">go to id</a>
<div style="margin-top:2000px;"></div>
<a id="id">id</a>
```

Comment: i do not mean sth that you said. i just added to make scrool in the page. exactly i could not understand what you mean. are you trying to do sth like this? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <body>
        <a href="#name">click me</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div name="name" id="name">here</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```