# HTML href to an element with an ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML code, I have a list element ID such as:

```
<li id="pageHome">
```

And, when I want to reference to it, I have:

```
<h1><a href="#!/pageHome" id="logo">Interior</a></h1>
```

This works fine, however, when I load my website, I noticed that when I want to go my home page, the link looks like this:

mywebsite.com/#!/pageHome

I don't think this looks professional. Is there anything that I can do such that anytime that I want to go to main page, it shows something like this instead?

mywebsite.com/pageHome

Comment: _"And, when I want to reference to it, I have:

`<h1><a href="#!/pageHome" id="logo">Interior</a></h1>`"_ No you don't. `href="#pageHome"` should do it.

Comment: what's the !/ for ? if it's on the same page it should be #pageHome

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a link like <a href="#id"> which link to the same page in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535699/how-to-write-a-link-like-a-href-id-which-link-to-the-same-page-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

The dash will always appear,  but you can prevent the backslash and exclamation mark from appearing in the url, as writing href="#pageHome" is sufficient

Comment: You might want to flag it as such in stead of answering

Answer (score 1):

`#pageHome` should work perfectly fine.

Also check [How do I scroll to an element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript) for JS solutions!